Trying to create a connection to Salesforce in Azure
As you may know, Azure has out-of-the-box connectors for access third party systems such as SF, and that is what I am trying to create.  I know nothing about SF so this has proved to be a bit of a challenge.  I am using the Trailhead sandbox for devs.
I found a guide that showed how to set this up for Azure Data Factory, which isn't quite what I am doing, but the bulk of it is the same:

I created this connector app with oath2.
ultimately, I get this error:   error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
I was getting more generic errors before I had generated the key and secret, so I think I am on the right path.  I did some digging around and it looks like this might be the result of an auth provider not being set up.  If so, what provider am I setting up?  Any help would be GREATFULLY appreciated.
